# Should I apply ReLU to non negative output?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, tensorflow, keras

Suppose I want to predict the position of a sensor based on its reading.

I can first predict the unit vector and predict the distance to be multiplied to this vector.
And I know that distance will never be negative because all the negative parts are inside unit vector already.

**Should I apply ReLU to the distance before multiplying it to the unit vector?**

I'm thinking that this can be helpful to eliminate the network from needing too much training data by restricting the output ranges the network could give. But I also think that it could make the learning slower when the ReLU unit dies (value=0) so the gradient doesn't flow properly somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying a ReLU activation function to a non-negative number is the same as applying the identity activation function.

What you may wish to do is apply $\ln(|\vec{x}|)$, $\arctan(x[0], x[1])$, ..., $\arctan(x[0], x[N-1])$, where $N$ is the number of dimensions to $\vec{x}$, and pass this directly into a parameter matrix multiplication (which involves deliberately using an identity activation in the input layer in some frameworks). This typically improves speed, accuracy, and reliability of convergence when the magnitudes exhibit a distribution close to an exponential of Gaussian and the directional components are near Gaussian when expressed in radians.